# Does HTML5 change the standard for HTML commenting?

Tags: html, comments

Recently I found that there is, possibly, a new way of commenting in HTML5.

Instead of the typical `<!-- -->` multi-line commenting I've read about,  I *thought* I noticed that my IDE made a regular `<!div >` commented out. So I tested it out, and to my surprise Chrome had commented out that tag. It *only* commented out the tag and not the contents of the div, so I had to comment out the closer `<!/div>` to avoid closing other divs.

I tested another and it appears that generally putting an exclamation marker in front of the opening of any tag, this symbol `<`, makes that tag commented out.

Is this actually new? Is it bad practice? It is actually very convenient, but is it practical yet (if not new)?

**Extra details:**

Although a syntax error or misinterpretations of this particular syntax is a good reason, how come Chrome *actually* renders them as full comments?

**The code is written as**:

```
<!div displayed> some text here that is still displayed <!/div>
```

**And then it is rendered as**:

```
<!--div displayed--> some text here that is still displayed <!--/div-->
```

Comment: More likely it's simply a syntax error and/or nonsense tag and therefore ignored.

Comment: @deceze I somewhat expected that since browsers can be lenient with how they render html according to less strict rules.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew What IDE does that? According selected answer, we could report this as an issue (or fix it if's open source).

Comment: @Derecksonit I double checked my IDE after the official answer was made to make sure my eyes weren't deceiving me. It happened to be that it was not in de facto commented out, but was the regular text color which was similar. This was all by chance.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

There is no new standard for comments in HTML5. The only valid comment syntax is still `<!-- -->`. From [section 8.1.6 of W3C HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#comments):

> **Comments** must start with the four character sequence U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN, U+0021 EXCLAMATION MARK, U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS (`<!--`).

The `<!` syntax originates in SGML DTD markup, which is not part of HTML5. In HTML5, it is reserved for comments, CDATA sections, and the DOCTYPE declaration. Therefore whether this alternative is bad practice depends on whether you consider the use of (or worse, the dependence on) obsolete markup to be bad practice.

Validator.nu calls what you have a "Bogus comment." — which means that it's treated like a comment even though it's not a valid comment. This is presumably for backward compatibility with pre-HTML5, which was SGML-based, and had markup declarations that took the form `<!FOO>`, so I wouldn't call this new. The reason they're treated *like* comments is because SGML markup declarations were special declarations not meant to be rendered, but since they are meaningless in HTML5 (with the above exceptions), as far as the HTML5 DOM is concerned they *are* nothing more than comments.

The following steps within [section 8.2.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tokenization) lead to this conclusion, which Chrome appears to be following to the letter:

1. [8.2.4.1 Data state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#data-state):

   > Consume the next input character:
   >
   > **"<" (U+003C)**
   > Switch to the tag open state.
2. [8.2.4.8 Tag open state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tag-open-state):

   > Consume the next input character:
   >
   > **"!" (U+0021)**
   > Switch to the markup declaration open state.
3. [8.2.4.45 Markup declaration open state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#markup-declaration-open-state):

   > **If the next two characters are both "-" (U+002D) characters, consume those two characters, create a comment token whose data is the empty string, and switch to the comment start state.**
   >
   > Otherwise, if the next seven characters are an ASCII case-insensitive match for the word "DOCTYPE", then consume those characters and switch to the DOCTYPE state.
   >
   > Otherwise, if there is an adjusted current node and it is not an element in the HTML namespace and the next seven characters are a case-sensitive match for the string "[CDATA[" (the five uppercase letters "CDATA" with a U+005B LEFT SQUARE BRACKET character before and after), then consume those characters and switch to the CDATA section state.
   >
   > **Otherwise, this is a parse error. Switch to the bogus comment state. The next character that is consumed, if any, is the first character that will be in the comment.**

   Notice that it says to switch to the comment start state only if the sequence of characters encountered is `<!--`, otherwise it's a bogus comment. This reflects what is stated in section 8.1.6 above.
4. [8.2.4.44 Bogus comment state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#bogus-comment-state):

   > Consume every character up to and including the first ">" (U+003E) character or the end of the file (EOF), whichever comes first. Emit a comment token whose data is the concatenation of all the characters starting from and including the character that caused the state machine to switch into the bogus comment state, up to and including the character immediately before the last consumed character (i.e. up to the character just before the U+003E or EOF character), but with any U+0000 NULL characters replaced by U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER characters. (If the comment was started by the end of the file (EOF), the token is empty. Similarly, the token is empty if it was generated by the string "`<!>`".)

   In plain English, this turns `<!div displayed>` into `<!--div displayed-->` and `<!/div>` into `<!--/div-->`, exactly as described in the question.

On a final note, you can probably expect other HTML5-compliant parsers to behave the same as Chrome.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to find the official reasoning behind this incident. It clears things up quite a bit and gives a lot of validity to my wrongful assumption.

Comment: It's weird how the HTML5 spec has rules to process “invalid” content. If it's invalid, it shouldn't be processed at all.

Comment: Well, that's how HTML and web languages used to be - strict. The reason improper code structure is processed so leniently is for better quality sites. The more websites a browser can view, and correctly view with wrong syntax, the more happy their end users will be. The general web-standards writers (mostly w3 not the other one), realized that the browser vendors weren't following guidelines because of this. HTML5 came and only built on the idea to make design officially more lenient.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez: XHTML tried the "invalid content = error" approach and failed miserably. Besides, the rules basically says "don't parse this bogus comment, just treat it as comment and parse the next valid thing you find". So depending on your point of view, HTML5 either doesn't do what you want because what you want sucks or HTML5 does exactly what you want.

Comment: What an exotic way to define a grammar. I've never seen anything alike.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez: Historically, HTML servers would expect to serve the same sequence of characters to any kind of browser; although it is possible to design a document format in such a way that older parsers will be able to distinguish documents which use "optional" newer features that older parsers should ignore, documents which use vital newer features and should be rejected by browsers that don't support them, and documents which are just plain invalid, such a thing was not done with HTML during its formative years.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez: As a consequence, if browser saw `<fnorble>Woozle</fnorble>`, it had no way of knowing whether the document would be better presented by showing `Woozle` and ignoring the tags around it, by hiding the tags and everything between them, or triggering some kind of error.  If there had been a rule that given a structure like `<$fnorble>Woozle<!fnorble>Quack</fnorble>` a browser that understood `$fnorble` should process `Woozle` and ignore `Quack`, and one that didn't should ignore `Woozle` and process `Quack`, that might have helped, but no such general rule was ever defined.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think this is a good habit to take since `<!` stands for markup declarations like `<!DOCTYPE`. Thus you think it's commented (well... browser will try to interpret it).

Even if it doesn't appear, this seems not to be the correct syntax for commenting HTML code.

Comment: Although that **may** be true, how come Chrome actually makes those tags commented out, but now the doctype.

Comment: Suggestion (i'm not sure, just guessing): tries to interpret > can't > commented ?

Comment: That seems reasonable enough to me.

Comment: Again (sorry to insist), but be aware that this is just a supposition !